# .NET Core Dependency Injection in BaseController

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I've seen this code in many places but I'm having a hard time understanding what is happening.  It works, but it looks redundant to me.

`public abstract class BaseController<T> : ControllerBase where T : BaseController<T>`

I don't understand `where T : BaseController<T>`... this looks like a loop.

Comment: is it the syntax `where T: BaseController<T>` that you are trying to understand or the purpose of this ?

Comment: Take for example `class MyController: BaseController<MyController> { ... }` You tend to see this pattern when you want to the base controller to be aware of the derived controller.